# Swift protocol inside of protocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I am running into a problem with Swift protocols. I have something like this:

```swift
protocol OnboardingPage {
  var viewModel: OnboardingPageViewModel! { get }
}

protocol OnboardingPageViewModel {
  func getValue() -> Bool
}

// ---

class FirstNameViewController: UIViewController, OnboardingPage {
  var viewModel: FirstNameViewModel!
}

class FirstNameViewModel: OnboardingPageViewModel {
  func getValue() -> Bool {
    return true
  }
}

class GenderViewController: UIViewController, OnboardingPage {
  var viewModel: GenderViewModel!
}

class GenderViewModel: OnboardingPageViewModel {
  func getValue() -> Bool {
    return false
  }
}
```

I have a bunch of view controllers that confirm to the `OnboardingPage` protocol, and they all have a view model that all conform to the `OnboardingPageViewModel` protocol.

But sadly the code above doesn't work: it says `FirstNameViewController` doesn’t confirm to the `OnboardingPage` protocol, since its `viewModel` property has type `FirstNameViewModel` instead of `OnboardingPageViewModel` - even though `FirstNameViewModel` IS a `OnboardingPageViewModel`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: `Type that conforms to protocol` and `protocol` are not the same. `FirstNameViewModel` is not `OnboardingPage`. Also `T!` is not the same as `T`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct about the T!, I fixed my example (it was different in my real code).

Comment: FWIW your `getValue` function is vague. Get value of what?

Comment: Just an example to show the protocol and 2 implementations. Doesn't matter for the real question I think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use associated type** OnboardingPageViewModel type ViewModel

**Edited**

```swift
protocol OnboardingPage {
    associatedtype ViewModel: OnboardingPageViewModel

    var viewModel: ViewModel { get }
}

protocol OnboardingPageViewModel {
    func getValue() -> Bool
}

class FirstNameViewController: OnboardingPage {
    let viewModel: FirstNameViewModel

    init(viewModel: FirstNameViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
}

class FirstNameViewModel: OnboardingPageViewModel {
    func getValue() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

class GenderViewController: OnboardingPage {
    let viewModel: GenderViewModel

    init(viewModel: GenderViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
}

class GenderViewModel: OnboardingPageViewModel {
    func getValue() -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: if it's just one condition for the `associatedtype` you can even skip `where` and just declare it as `associatedtype ViewModel: OnboardingPageViewModel`

Comment: Thanks! However, now I am running into a new issue where I get the error `Protocol 'OnboardingPage' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements` when I try to do something like this, in my container view controller: `let pages: [OnboardingPage] = [FirstNameViewController(), GenderViewController()]`.

Comment: does usage of `where` still apply? If so can you include it some place in your code. Otherwise it's confusing, because readers like me are looking for your usage but end up with nothing :|

Answer (score 0):

You may solve your pages array [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58801101/swift-protocol-inside-of-protocol/58807639#comment103884353_58801387) with deletion of associatedtype:

```
protocol OnboardingPage {    
    var viewModel: OnboardingPageViewModel { get }
}

protocol OnboardingPageViewModel {
    func getValue() -> Bool
}

class FirstNameViewModel: OnboardingPageViewModel {
    func getValue() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

class FirstNameViewController: OnboardingPage {
    let viewModel: OnboardingPageViewModel

    init(viewModel: FirstNameViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
}

class GenderViewModel: OnboardingPageViewModel {
    func getValue() -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}

class GenderViewController: OnboardingPage {
    let viewModel: OnboardingPageViewModel

    init(viewModel: GenderViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let nameModel = FirstNameViewModel()
let genderModel = GenderViewModel()

let array: [OnboardingPage] = [FirstNameViewController(viewModel: nameModel), GenderViewController(viewModel: genderModel)]

for page in array {
    print(page.viewModel.getValue())
}
```

However, in such manner concrete types of your models will not be available for callers of `OnboardingPage` conforming classes. You may try to solve it with implementing visitor pattern within `OnboardingPage` or enhancing its capabilities.

Of course, you can always write `let pages: [Any] = [FirstNameViewController(), GenderViewController()]` using Cruz example, but it is ugly as it goes, and I strongly discourage you from using `Any` in your API if possible.